# django settings default time zone

Tags: django, timezone

here is a question i can use django time zone for utc and it worked fine
but when i switch the default time zone to 'Asia/Tehran' it wont work and i get the error

```
ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: ASIA/TEHRAN
```

the actual code in settings.py is:

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tehran'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

and it is on django time zone list i checked it

the system is ubuntu 20 and django version is 3.2

Comment: What error you are getting actually

Comment: ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting: ASIA/TEHRAN

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: Incorrect timezone setting while migrating manage.py file in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182557/valueerror-incorrect-timezone-setting-while-migrating-manage-py-file-in-django)

Comment: Try to add ```TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Dhaka'```

Comment: Are you on Linux?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56893712/11475846

Comment: You can also set ```TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'```

Comment: no it is not fix my problem and my timezone folder is full and have the asia folder and Tehran in it

Comment: and tzdata is installed and it is newest version btw

Comment: Try with other same timezone like `Asia/Muscat` (utc + 4) or others utc + 4 timezone and let us know

Comment: just check it asia/muscat have no problem

Comment: Try to set USE_L10N to 'False'

Comment: l10N false not working either

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC+3:30'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```